# How to insert video in database using C# Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making C# windows form application. How I can insert video in database from my webcam?
In MS SQL there are many types for example picture, nvarchar.. Which one must I choose? 
And how I can connect my webcam to my winform to record video?

Comment: Datatype would be image or VarBinary, however storing that sort of data in a db should be thought about, storing it as a file and then storing the filename would be a better choice. As for .net and web cams a cursory google would have found something like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202464/How-to-use-a-WebCam-in-C-with-the-NET-Framework

Comment: Perhaps this codeplex page can help http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no type for storing a video in a database but it's clearly not the way to go because the transactions with a database should be as fast as possible. To achieve what you want I would recommend either using FILESTREAM or inserting manually the path to your file in the database.

The point is that it's not a good idea to store something as big as a movie or any other media file in a database. Filestream allows you to write code which will make you think that you are putting the file in your database but the Database Management System actually put the file on the file system and the good thing is that you don't need to be aware of it and to manage all the logic behind. However one the drawback of using Filestream is that you won't be able to rely on Entity Framework which makes it easy to manage interactions with a database.

The second option which consist in saving the file on the hard disk manually and referencing the path in the database is not necessarily difficult to implement, you just need to be careful and to avoid doing mistakes such as leaving a file on the disk and deleting the corresponding entry in the database.

**Update**  Yeah [I've read too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188362.aspx) quickly, varbinary allows to store stuff greater than 8000 bytes so it would allow you to achieve what you want. But I maintain that it's not a good idea to store the file directly in your database.